# Cambiar el directorio de imagenes subidas en wordpress a uno fuera del directorio

Tags: laravel, wordpress

Os comento estoy con un proyecto el cual estoy usando laravel y wordpress, y necesito que las imágenes que sean subidas desde wordpress, estén en una carpeta fuera del proyecto de la carpeta de wordpress es decir necesito que este en una carpeta en "public", ya que estoy usando wordpress para un sistema de blog para mi aplicacion en laravel, y necesito que no haya ninguna referencia en la url sobre donde esta wordpress (Razones de seguridad), ya que el contenido de los posts son traidos desde Corcel.

Es decir:

- Public (Directorio padre)
- Directorio proyecto Wordpress (Directorio hijo)
- img_blog(Directorio hijo)

Necesito que las imagenes que sean guardadas en el "Directorio proyecto wordpress", cambiar el directorio por "img_blog".

Llevo atascado un tiempo y no lo consigo...
Gracias ^^

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba este método.
Edita tu fichero wp-config.php agregando al final este código:

```
   define('UPLOADS', 'wp-content/myimages');
```

Siendo **'wp-content/myimages'** el nuevo directorio, es decir, si lo necesitas fuera de la carpeta Wordpress pondría: **'../la-carpeta-que-quieras-poner'**

**¡¡¡IMPORTANTE!!!**

**Asegurate que lo escribes antes de:**

```
   require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-settings.php');
```